# js array observe change then loop push operation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have realize a function while array push operator it perform certain operations.

---

like below: when push data it will call `refreshView` one times;
but when loop 100 times push operation it will call `refreshView` 100 times;

---

**any idea to call the last one `refreshView()` when finish loop**

```js
var arr = [];

arr.push = function () {
  Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);
  refreshView();
}

function refreshView() {
  // perform some operations
}

arr.push(1);    // it will call refreshView() 1 times;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  arr.push(i);   // it will call refreshView() 100 times, how can i call refreshView() once after loop finish..
}
```

Comment: No idea what you're asking. Just call `notifyDataChange()` explicitly after your loop?

Comment: try adding `if (i === 99){ notifyDataChange(); }` after `arr.push(i);` within your for loop

Comment: @Sam0  no, every push operator it will call refreshView once..

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen the notifyDataChange() just change refreshView() ，can you understant ?

Comment: So you don't want `refreshView()` executed on every push? Why are you putting it in your `push()` method then?

Comment: this may be a framework style request where array watching is required. You will find it in the rivets framework (http://rivetsjs.com/). Although going forward JS proxys are the future for this (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option is to use a timeout to delay the function call, so should only run when finished:

```
var arr = [];
var timer;

arr.push = function () {
  Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);

  if(timer)
  {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  )

  timer = setTimeout(refreshView, 10);
}

function refreshView() {
  // perform some operations
}

arr.push(1);    // it will call refreshView() 1 times;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  arr.push(i);   // it will call refreshView() 100 times, how can i call refreshView() once after loop finish..
}
```